# wso2am Elastic Search lookup

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I switched from Apigee to WSO2 2.1 but on piece of functionality is missing.

When my Oauth users make API calls, I want to add an additional Header
to the backend request. E.g.:  "X-Customer-Name: CUST_NAME

I have the Java code to lookup "CUST_NAME" in ElasticSearch based on
the user's consumer key & secret. How would I integrate that code into
WSO2 to be able to lookup the values and send the extra X-Customer-Name header to my backend?

Comment: Do you need to call this for each API Invocation?

Comment: Yes, I'd want to do an ES query on every API request.
I found [this page](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Passing+Enduser+Attributes+to+the+Backend+Using+JWT) but I can't find the maven dependencies to add to my pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java classes can be integrated / used in WSO2 mediations using `<class/>` mediator.

To achieve this, the custom java class can extend AbstractMediator class and can implement the logic in the mediate method.

Create a new insequence, like the following and invoke the custom class, this way the custom property can be set to the message context.

```
<sequence name="TokenExchange" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <class description="" name="com.customer.CustomerName"/>
    <property expression="get-property('Customer-Name','custName')" name="cs" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
</sequence>
```

Use this newly built inSequence into your API In-Flow message mediation flow and pass the appropriate properties to the backend.

Comment: Ok. Are there any code examples for that?

I tried extending a class mentioned in the [Passing Enduser Attributes to the Backend Using JWT](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Passing+Enduser+Attributes+to+the+Backend+Using+JWT) page but I couldn't figure out how to configure my dependencies in the pom.xml.